# Detecting changes in database after regular intervals of time

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, email

I've got a table (**tbl_mark6_trainee**) in an Oracle database. This table has a field called "**status**". Every time a user registers himself on my application, a new row is created in this table with the default value of "status" being set to "**Incomplete**".

The web application I'm creating must e-mail the admin(s) of this application if the value of this field ("status") doesn't change (from "Incomplete" to "Complete") within **7** days of a new user registering on this site.

The technologies I'm working with is C#.net.

I've got the E-mail bit handled. How do I check the status of that field every 7 days without any human intervention?

Comment: If I follow you correctly, does that table have a column for insertion date and time? If so you could run a query daily for rows which are <= 7 days old and status = 'incomplete'.

Comment: Yes. It has a field which records the current date and time. But, the thing is I do not want the admin to log in and fire a query. I just want him to be informed via e-mail.

So.. how do I ensure that the application automatically runs a query every 7 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Complete database approach

You can create a procedure which will check for the members with no change in 7 days with help of a query. And **utl_mail** to send email.

And using **dbms_job** and **dbms_schedule** to launch it on a specific time every day.

### Combination of db and front end

Write a procedure to return the member list who were not changed status in last 7 days.

The member list from procedure is captured in front end and email be sent.

Query for no status change in 7 days is simple.

select * from table where status = 'INCOMPLETE' and date <=sysdate-7;

Comment: Yes, but what I really need is to find a way to do something so that that query is fired automatically say after every two days or every day at midnight WITHOUT any human intervention. What would be a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: I have mentioned that in the answer. call the query or a stored procedure from your front end or back end with help of a scheduler. In oracle, we have dbms_scheduler and in unix we have cronjob and in windows you have windows scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a console application that does the checking and calls email sending script. Add it to scheuduled tasks/chron jobs and make it execute every 7 days.

OR

I have never used oracle, but maybe it can do a chron job and call some app or script by itself?

Comment: Isn't there any alternative to this?

Comment: You can try combining triggers and sql email sending:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i6052
http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum112/291.htm

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine that something didn't happen within seven days, the original date that the row was added must be stored somewhere. I would add another column to this table to store this date by modifying the code that added this row. Another possibility would be add an insert trigger to store the column at the database layer.

In any case, once you have the original creation date stored, the query would be something like

```
select * 
  from table_name 
 where created_date < sysdate - 7 
   and status = 'Incomplete';
```

which will give you the items that were created more than 7 days ago and the status is still incomplete. Then you can run this query using another process on a regular interval (say every midnight) to find incomplete registrations and send the right people the email.